# what is difference between extended and extend_object hook

Tags: ruby

can someone explain the difference between extended and extend_object hook. There is no proper documentation on the internet for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, `extend_object` is the method that does the extending. You can override it to for example create a typecheck before extend happens:

```
module Foo
  def self.extend_object(obj)
    raise(TypeError, "No strings!") if obj.is_a?(String)
    super # need to call super or object
          # won't be extended
  end

  def self.extended(obj)
    puts "#{obj.inspect} was extended with #{self}"
  end
end

1.extend(Foo)
"1".extend(Foo) # raises TypeError: No strings!
```

Comment: why do we need super keyword /

Comment: Because otherwise the object won't be extended.

Comment: so its not `before_extended` - it's *the* method doing extension. If you override it without calling `super` you'll be unable to extend.

Answer (score 0):

`extend_object` is a private API method used by `extend` and it adds module constants and methods

> `extend_object(p1) private`
>
> Extends the specified object by adding this module’s constants and methods (which are added as singleton methods). This is the callback method used by `Object#extend`.

https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/extend_object

`extended` is just a callback that can be used by a developer to run specific code when a module is being extended.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-extended

Comment: extend_object and extended both are hooks and are called automatically whenever i extend module in my class , so what is the need of extend_object ?

Comment: As the docs says - it extends an object using the module - it does the job. You probably don't have to touch it.